# adding arrow keys to ngx-material-keyboard

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using ngx-material-keyboard/core and I have a requirement to add arrow keys like so, to the right of the standard keyboard:

[image]

I was looking through the docs here:
https://github.com/joskwanten/core#providing-custom-layouts

and its not clear to me how to achieve this. this is what I tried so far:

````
export const customTextKeyPadLayouts: IKeyboardLayouts = {
...keyboardLayouts,
'Notes Layout': {
  name: 'Protocol Notes layout',
  keys: [
    [['`'], ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['6'], ['7'], ['8'], ['9'], ['0'], [KeyboardClassKey.Bksp], [''], ['^']],
    [['Q'], ['W'], ['E'], ['R'], ['T'], ['Y'], ['U'], ['I'], ['O'], ['P'], ['['], [']'], ['\'']],
    [['A'], ['S'], ['D'], ['F'], ['H'], ['J'], ['K'], ['L'], [';'], [',']],
    [['Z'], ['X'], ['C'], ['V'], ['B'], ['N'], ['M'], [','], ['.']],
    [[KeyboardClassKey.Space]]
  ],
  lang: ['protocol-notes-text']
},
};```
````

in the first row of the `keys` array you can see that I added:
, [''], ['^']],

in an attempt to mock the up arrow, but obviously that doesn't lead the desired behavior of moving the cursor up, but instead inserts a caret (^). is there any way to add an arrow control field with the default layouts?

the `KeyboardClassKey` referenced above only has limited characters, no arrows are available.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code in the GitHub [repository](https://github.com/ngx-material-keyboard/core) of the project, what you want to achieve will not be possible unless you want to fork the project and handle arrow keys in [keyboard-key.component.ts](https://github.com/ngx-material-keyboard/core/blob/d076ea9e1f0cd6f861fdf2bca66ab4bbaf905588/src/core/src/components/keyboard-key/keyboard-key.component.ts).

or look for other alternatives such as [this](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard) one.